# RGBDSLAM make problem: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a question, but wanted to post this in case anyone else had the same problem. I had a problem makeing the RGBDSLAM tool from OpenSlam.org. I had the following error when trying to build it...
...

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rgbdslam

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[3]: *** [../bin/rgbdslam] Error 1

make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/aaron/myRosDir/rgbdslam/build'

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/aaron/myRosDir/rgbdslam/build'

make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/aaron/myRosDir/rgbdslam/build'

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Taking a wild guess I downloaded GSL from GNU Scientific Library

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

And the build completed!

ps. this is my first post. How do I make code show up in a scrollable window?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9805/rgbdslam-make-problem:-/usr/bin/ld:-cannot-find--lgsl/) by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3460 on 2011-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-04-22**:
For code formatting, indent with 4 spaces (Ctrl+K is the shortcut, or use the little "101010" icon). Or sometimes just wait and someone will edit your post for you. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you figured out the problem. However, just as a general tip, whenever you encounter an error like that, it's best to look in your Synaptic Package Manager to see if you can easily download that missing packages.

If that doesn't work, you can typically google search the missing piece. That's what works for me every time.

-Shark

---

Originally posted by [Shark](https://answers.ros.org/users/264/shark/) with karma: 241 on 2011-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2011-04-25**:
Thanks, I'll remember that. I'm new to linux so I didn't even know about SPM.